# What's the most effective function in julia to do a task inside a loop?

Tags: parallel-processing, julia, distributed

Good day everyone,

basically I have this:

```
@sync @parallel for i in 1:100;
     V[i] = i
end
```

And I really have no problems at all. I'm working with julia 0.6.4 and I've noticed that the function `@parallel` doesn't exist in the new releases. So my question is: there's a more efficient way to run in parallel that simple task? maybe in other versions of Julia. The function `@distributed` does the same?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're updating code from 0.6 to 1.0, step through 0.7 first.  It's literally *exactly the same as 1.0*, but with friendly warnings that tell you how to update your code!  And yes, in this case, it'll tell you to use `@distributed` instead of `@parallel` and to load the Distributed standard library.

```
julia> @sync @parallel for i in 1:100;
            V[i] = i
       end
WARNING: Base.@parallel is deprecated: it has been moved to the standard library package `Distributed`.
Add `using Distributed` to your imports.
 in module Main
┌ Warning: `@parallel` is deprecated, use `@distributed` instead.
│   caller = eval(::Module, ::Any) at boot.jl:319
└ @ Core ./boot.jl:319
```

This was simply a rename, and a rename for a good reason: there are many forms of parallelism and the "most effective" form of parallelism for you will depend upon what task you're doing (in particular its runtime and IO) and the hardware you have available.